# Alternative quaternion multiplication method

Tags: quaternions

Given two quaternions, $a+bi+cj+dk$ and $e+fi+gj+hk$, their product (w.r.t. their given order) would normally be given by $Q_1+Q_2i+Q_3j+Q_4k=(ae-bf-cg-dh)+(af+be+ch-dg)i+(ag-bh+ce+df)j+(ah+bg-cf+de)k$. This takes a total of $16$ real multiplications and $12$ real additions to accomplish.

I'm looking to reduce the number of multiplications. Here's what I have so far.

$P_1=(c+d)(g+h)$, $P_2=(a+b)(e+f)$, $P_3=(c+d)(e+f)$, $P_4=(a+b)(g+h)$, $Q_1=(ae+dg)+(ch-bf)-P_1$, $Q_2=P_2+(ch-bf)-(ae+dg)$, $Q_3=P_3+(ag-de)-(bh+cf)$, $Q_4=P_4-(ag-de)-(bh+cf)$.

As far as I can tell, this requires 12 real multiplications and 16 real additions, assuming certain quantities are reused.

Are there any well-known methods for doing this using less real multiplications, or any obvious simplifications that I could make to my formulas?

EDIT: You can calculate $(R_1,R_2)=(ae+dg,ag-de)$ and $(R_3,R_4)=(cf+bh,ch-bf)$ by this method: $S_1=(a+d)(e+g)$, $S_2=(c+b)(f+h)$, $(R_1,R_2)=(S_1-ag-de,ag-de)$, $(R_3,R_4)=(S_2-ch-bf, ch-bf)$. This brings the total number of real multiplications down to 10, and the real additions up to 22.

Comment: Identifying quaternions as a two-by-two matrices with complex entries, via $$a+bi+cj+dk\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cc}a+bI&c+dI\\-c+dI&a-bI\end{array}\right),$$ where $I=\sqrt{-1}$, makes life easier at the multiplication time.

Comment: It's convenient notationally, but does it offer any insight towards an efficient algorithm?

Comment: Multiplying matrices is pretty agile. Instead of three imaginary units only you need one.

Comment: The least amount of real mults that I know of to do a complex multiplication is 3. A matrix multiplication of this kind, without any simplification, would then require 24 real mults.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an algorithm [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0041555377901872/1-s2.0-0041555377901872-main.pdf?_tid=a659a59c-9b82-11e4-b682-00000aacb361&acdnat=1421194796_3ca78b306a2859fdd3f1b9be1136bc3d) that uses eight multiplications, as long as you don't count multiplications by $2$ and by $-1$. This paper also mentions a proof that it can't be done with less than seven. [Here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/pdf/398163.pdf?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=&s5=&s6=&s7=quaternion%20multiplication&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=27) is a review of an article which shows it can't be done with less than ten multiplications if you count multiplying by fixed constants, and gives such an algorithm, but I can't see the paper (due to paywalls I don't know if either of these links will work.)

The algorithm in the first paper is as follows: $(a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k)(b_0+b_1i+b_2j+b_3k)=c_0+c_1 i+c_2j+c_3k$, where
$$\begin{pmatrix} -c_0&c_1&c_2&c_3\end{pmatrix}=1/4\begin{pmatrix} n_0p_0&n_1p_1&n_2p_2&n_3p_3\end{pmatrix} A-2\begin{pmatrix} a_0b_0&a_3b_2&a_2b_1&a_1b_3\end{pmatrix} $$
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1\\ 1&-1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$                $$\begin{pmatrix} n_0&n_1&n_2&n_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_0&a_1&a_2&a_3\end{pmatrix} A$$$$\begin{pmatrix} p_0&p_1&p_2&p_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} b_0&b_1&b_2&b_3\end{pmatrix}A$$
So the only "real" multiplications being down are between $n$s and $p$s and between $a$s and $b$s in the final formula.

Comment: Well, the multiplication by 2 and division by 4 can be accomplished via bitshift, so those wouldn't count as true mults. This has an awful lot of additions to get the mults down, though.

Answer (score 1):

One method from the [internetz](http://ariya.blogspot.com/2010/07/faster-quaternion-multiplication.html)

$$ \begin{align}
A_1 & = (d + b) * (f + g) \\
 A_3 &= (a - c) * (e + h) \\
 A_4 &= (a + c) * (e - h) \\
 A_2 &= A_1 + A_3 + A_4 \\
 A_5 &= 0.5 * (A_2 + (d - b) * (f - g)) \\ \\
Q_1 &= A_5 - A_1 + (d - c) * (g - h)\\
Q_2 &= A_5 - A_2 + (b + a) * (f + e)\\
Q_3 &= A_5 - A_3 + (a - b) * (g + h)\\
Q_4 &= A_5 - A_4 + (d + c) * (e - f)\\
\end{align} $$

9 multiplications highlighted with "*" (including one divide-by-2)

checked, seems to work OK.